# Render element of DataGrid cell outside the cell bounds

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

The red rectangles in the example below are clipped (except the last row) and I'd like to know if it's possible to translate transform a control inside a data grid cell outside of the cell?

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="WpfSamples.Transforms.TranslateOutOfContainer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TranslateOutOfContainer" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Grid Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="10" Height="10">
                                <StackPanel ClipToBounds="False">
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="5">
                                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform Y="3"/>
                                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <System:Object/>
        <System:Object/>
        <System:Object/>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You are drawing outside cell bound. The problem here is ZIndex of the items. Rows below are drawn over (after) rows above. Adding `TranslateTrasform` does not affect order in which things are drawn. In the same way columns on the right will be drawn after (over) columns on the left.

Comment: I've tried setting the Panel.ZIndex of the rectangle but that makes no difference.

Comment: `Panel.ZIndex` works only on direct children of a `Panel` and only within that panel. But it won't help you much as you have one panel per row to store columns (drawn left to right) and then all rows are in another panel (drawn top to bottom). You would have to use something that draws above everything else like a `Popup`. Downside is that it will draw above **every window**, even if your window is inactive